# How do i improve this mysql query for performance

Tags: php, mysql, myisam

i have a slow query in php on a large mysql MyISAM table:

```
select p.*, m.*, d.* 
from datafeeds as d, 
     products as p left outer join meta as m on p.mykey = m.mykey 
where p.datafeed_id = d.id and "keyword"
```

The table has 3 Million records and this search query is taking up to 50 seconds in some cases.

I would be more than thankful for a hint to optimize the query and/or table and indexes.

datafeed_id has index BTREE
mykey_index has index BTREE

I tryed EXPLAIN EXTENDED:

EXPLAIN EXTENDED SELECT p. * , m. * , d. *
FROM datafeeds AS d, products AS p
LEFT OUTER JOIN meta AS m ON p.mykey = m.mykey
WHERE p.datafeed_id = d.id
AND "keyword"

id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra
1      | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Impossible WHERE

Comment: You're not going to get any performance increase if you continue to select * from each table

Comment: To others: Is having the p & d relationship in the WHERE causing any slowdowns or is it just style at that point?

Comment: Maybe you should check out http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Can you post an example of `$name_clause`?

Comment: also left outer join is painful to! Can we see table structure to? Need to know what keys have been indexed and what keys your jumping through in your $name_clause

Comment: @DerekKromm which columns are returned isn't going to have much of an effect on the performance. the problem most likely lies with indexes.

Answer (score 1):

make sure that `p.datafeed_id`, and `m.mykey` have been indexed. would also be helpful to know what is contained in `$name_clause`. You may also want to take a look at MySQL's EXPLAIN, as it helps you narrow down what indexes are being used in given SELECT statements.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

post the result for a better answer.

Comment: datafeed_id has index BTREE mykey_index has index BTREE. 

I tryed EXPLAIN EXTENDED - see results above.